# Botched Redmine Install

Tags: ruby, redmine

I've managed to botch an install of Redmine on an Ubuntu 11.10 machine. I'm getting a 404 when I try to access Redmine and the logs in /var/log/apache2/error.log are stating `File does not exist: /var/www/default`. Trying to run `script/about` from the Redmine directory (in this case `/usr/share/redmine` tells me I'm missing the `rubytree` gem. Any ideas as to how to correct this?

Comment: Did you try to install rubytree gem?

Comment: Yes, it was already installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed a newer version of Redmine that didn't look for this particular gem.